# Chromium browser instance as a service

Tags: node.js, docker, google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I'm working on web scraping application that uses node.js, puppeteer and Chromium. When I run the script it launches Chromium browser and executes the script using puppeteer package for scraping a web page.

To improve the performance I want to eliminate the launching of the Chromium browser instance.

I thinking of Chromium browser instance as a service so that I can connect to it and execute the script. Just like a database pooling connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the "browserless/chrome" docker. [Take a look at it](https://hub.docker.com/r/browserless/chrome/).

To eliminate the launching of the Chromium instance, I use it like this:

```sh
docker run -e "PREBOOT_CHROME=true" -e "EXIT_ON_HEALTH_FAILURE=true" -e "CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=3600000" browserless/chrome
```

The flag that you are looking for is the "PREBOOT_CHROME=true". The other ones works for my use case, but maybe you don't need it. Take a look at the docs.

Regards.